# More values winzorized than outliers found?

Tags: r

Here my dataset that I am working with:

```
 df<-read.table(header=T,text="
group, test1
2,  8212
 2, 10025
 2,  7054
 2,  9462
 2,  9875
 2,  8403
 2,  9566
 2,  7276
2 , 9488
2,  9515
2, 11322
2, 10037
2,  9885
2, 10090
2,  9013
2 , 8682
 2, 10356
2 , 9545
2 , 9646
 2,  9186
2 , 8464
 2,  8870
 2,  9095
 2,  8301
 2, 10961
 2, 11102
 2,  9710
 2, 10343
 2, 10828
 2 , 7371
2  ,8125
2 , 8047
2 , 9028
 2 , 8149
 2,  9974
 2, 10255
 2,  9583
 2,  8423
 2,  9089
 1, 10915
 1,  9820
 1,  9809
 1,  9071
 1, 10610
  1,  9258
  1,  9047
 1 , 7444
  1, 10250
 1 , 9538
 1 ,10107
 1 ,10080
 1 , 9189
 1 ,10319
 1 , 8108
  1 ,10891
 1 , 7471
1 ,11864
 1 ,10653
1 , 9322
 1,  9609
 1,  8982
  1,  9962
 1, 10013
 1,  9832
  1, 10270
 1,  8882
1,  8035
1,  9103
1, 10103
1, 11999
1,  7265
1,  9457
1,  9049
1,  9166
1,  9701
1,  9465
1, 10298
1,  8404
1, 11771
1, 10249
1,  9036
1,  8056
1,  9356
1  9827")
```

There are two things I needed to do. I first needed to identify how many outliers existed for test1 BY group (2, 1).

I found that were 5 outliers from both groups using the following the function:

```
outlier <- function(x, SD = 2){
  mu <- mean(x)
  sigma <- sd(x)
  out <- x < mu - SD*sigma | x > mu + SD*sigma
  out
}
with(df, ave(test1, group, FUN = outlier)) # 5 outliers
```

I then proceeded to winsorize these outliers using the following:

```
library(robustHD)

df.wins= df%>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(measure_winsorized.test1 = winsorize(test1))
```

The only problem is when I look at how many values were winzorized (10) versus how many were initially outliers (5) the two are not the same. The same number of outliers should have been winsorized

Is the code incorrect or I am misunderstanding what I did?

Comment: Look into the `winsorize` function that you used. I see functions with that name in the packages `statar`, `broman`, `spatialEco`, `robustHD`, and `copynumber`. Does the documentation provide clues as to how it decides which values to Winsorize? My guess it yes, it does, and that it is a criteria other than 2 SDs from the mean. For example, if we look at the version in the [broman package](https://github.com/kbroman/broman/blob/master/R/winsorize.R), you can specify a quantile beyond which to Winsorize, and the default is 0.006, so 1.2% of values will be Winsorized.

Comment: Overall, I would say yes, you are misunderstanding. I did not look at the implementation in all those packages, but usually Winsorization is based on quantiles, not z-score, so it would be surprising if you got the same number of "outliers" from two pretty different methods.

Comment: @Gregor that is a good point. I have switched to using `library(broman)` so I can specify the quantile. I have updated the code to be: `df.wins= df%>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(measure_winsorized.test1 = winsorize(test1,q=0.975))` which seems to have help much more. I now have 6 winsorizations while 5 outliers still exist. Is there anyway I can make these match?

Comment: Sure, change your initial definition of "outlier" to use quantiles, not mean +/- standard deviations. Then it will match typical winsorization procedures. You can look at the `winsorize` code and modify it, [it's a pretty simple function](https://github.com/kbroman/broman/blob/master/R/winsorize.R#L36).

Comment: I am fairly new to R so I am just trying to make sure I am understanding what I am doing in my code and why I am getting the difference

Comment: Winsorization isn't based on mean +/- SD. It is based on quantilies. This is different. You could write your own function that modifies the data based on mean +/- 2 SD cut-off. It wouldn't be winsorization anymore, because that's not what winsorization does, but if could be your own variation.

Comment: Oh, okay. I see what you are saying...so if I wanted to alter my `outlier` function above, how could I modify it so as to get outliers using quantiles instead?

Comment: `outlier = function(x, q) {lohi <- quantile(x, c(q, 1-q), na.rm=TRUE); x < lohi[1]  | x > lohi[2]}` should do it. `q` is the quantile of data you want to flag off of each end. E.g., if you set `q = 0.1`, you'll flag the bottom 10% and the top 10% as outliers.